# Copying embeddings for gensim word2vec

Tags: word2vec, word-embeddings, gensim

I wanted to see if I can simply set new weights for gensim's Word2Vec without training. I get the 20 News Group data set from scikit-learn (from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups) and trained an instance of Word2Vec on it:

```
model_w2v = models.Word2Vec(sg = 1, size=300)
model_w2v.build_vocab(all_tokens)
model_w2v.train(all_tokens, total_examples=model_w2v.corpus_count, epochs = 30)
```

Here all_tokens is the tokenized data set. 
Then I created a new instance of Word2Vec without training

```
model_w2v_new = models.Word2Vec(sg = 1, size=300)
model_w2v_new.build_vocab(all_tokens)
```

and set the embeddings of the new Word2Vec equal to the first one

```
model_w2v_new.wv.vectors = model_w2v.wv.vectors
```

Most of the functions work as expected, e.g.

```
model_w2v.wv.similarity( w1='religion', w2 = 'religions')
> 0.4796233
model_w2v_new.wv.similarity( w1='religion', w2 = 'religions')
> 0.4796233
```

and

```
model_w2v.wv.words_closer_than(w1='religion', w2 = 'judaism')
> ['religions']
model_w2v_new.wv.words_closer_than(w1='religion', w2 = 'judaism')
> ['religions']
```

and

```
entities_list = list(model_w2v.wv.vocab.keys()).remove('religion')

model_w2v.wv.most_similar_to_given(entity1='religion',entities_list = entities_list)
> 'religions'
model_w2v_new.wv.most_similar_to_given(entity1='religion',entities_list = entities_list)
> 'religions'
```

However, most_similar doesn't work:

```
model_w2v.wv.most_similar(positive=['religion'], topn=3)
[('religions', 0.4796232581138611),
 ('judaism', 0.4426296651363373),
 ('theists', 0.43141329288482666)]

model_w2v_new.wv.most_similar(positive=['religion'], topn=3)
>[('roderick', 0.22643062472343445),
> ('nci', 0.21744996309280396),
> ('soviet', 0.20012077689170837)]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The answer to this question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591149/copying-embeddings-for-gensim-word2vec)